# Whats the difference between those two prime number checking algorithms

Tags: python, primes

so recently I've been trying to figure out algorithm which is supposed to check whether the number is prime or not. So I came up with an idea and made the code look like this:

```
def if_prime(num):
   
    for divisor in range(2,num):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"
        else:
            return f"{num} is prime"
print(if_prime(9))
```

So basically this code returns the wrong value, it says that 9 is a prime number and obviously it is not, however the following code seems to work, and I have no idea what's the difference.

```
def if_prime(num):
    for divisor in range(2,num):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"                                      
    return f"{num} is prime"

print(if_prime(9))
```

Comment: The first one never looks at a divisor other than 2; it returns a string whether or not `num % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot difference!

The first one is wrong!:

```
def if_prime(num):
   
    for divisor in range(2,num):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"
        else:
            return f"{num} is prime"
```

This checks whether a number has any factor between 0 and num and if it finds a factor it returns saying that the number is not prime.

But the mistake is that if it does not find a factor then it returns true at once and does not check for other divisors:

For example this will say that 9 is a prime number is it is not divisible by 2 and the if condition becomes false!

On the other hand the second one is correct! :

```
def if_prime(num):
    for divisor in range(2,num):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"                                      
    return f"{num} is prime"
```

In this one too we loop through all the divisors from 2 to num but in this case we do not return anything if one number is not a divisor( we check through all the possible divisors ) thus if the loop ends and we find no divisor then it means it is a prime number!

But this too has a small bug as it will say 1 is a prime number!

Here is a proper and efficient version of the if_prime function:

```
def if_prime(num):
    for divisor in range(2, num/2):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"                                      
    if num == 1:
        return f"{num} is not prime"
    else:
        return f"{num} is prime"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, the

```
else:
    return f"{num} is prime"
```

Breaks your for loop after the first iteration because return stops your loop and returns the value from the method

In your 2nd example,
the

```
return f"{num} is prime"
```

is only executed once the for loop ran to completion without finding a non prime value to return

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your first function is that it returns a false positive if num isn't divisible by 2. If the num is not divisible by 2, you need to keep going further. This is corrected in your second function.

```
def if_prime(num):
    for divisor in range(2, num):
        if (num % divisor) == 0:
            return f"{num} is not prime"
    return f"{num} is prime"
```

Here, the only way the else statement is going to be executed is when the if-statement won't return anything. It simply means that you did not find a divisor from 2 to num. So it MUST mean that num is prime. Hence it returns num as prime.